# How to apply horizontal css to divs

Tags: html, css, center

How do I make divs one, two, three horizontal with css?

[text-align: center](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) only puts them vertical?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="one">One</div>
   <div class="two">Two</div>
   <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

**Js Code:**

```
$(".container").css({
    "position": "fixed", 
    "margin":"0", 
    "left": "0px", 
    "right": "0px", 
    "height": "auto", 
    "min-height": "50px", 
    "z-index": "255", 
    "color": "white", 
    "line-height": "50px", 
    "padding": "16px", 
    "font-size": "1em",
    "text-align": "center", 
    "bottom": "0px", 
    "opacity": "1", 
    "background": "black"
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: pls post your css code

Comment: set property display to inline-block i.e display:inline-block

Comment: don't use javascript for this

Answer (score 1):

Set a width and apply `display:inline-block` in CSS
Like this:

```
.container div {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: $("body").prepend('<div class="stickyDiv"><div class="one">One</div><div class="two">Two</div><div class="three">Three</div></div>');

$(".stickyDiv").css({"width":"100px","display":"inline-block"});

Comment: Does not seem to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I have'nt the CSS when I've posted, so with `position:fixed`, it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block;` could make it works.

`float: left;` will not works because it will puts all your `div` elements to the `left` instead of `center` (it will erase the `text-align: center;` property you put on `.container`)

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/dbusktjd/1/)

By the way, why are you applying style with jQuery instead of CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to try 'float:left'